# Is there a parser/way available to parse Wikipedia dump files using Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, wiki, wikipedia

I have a project where I collect all the Wikipedia articles belonging to a particular category, pull out the dump from Wikipedia, and put it into our db.

So I should be parsing the Wikipedia dump file to get the stuff done. Do we have an efficient parser to do this job? I am a python developer. So I prefer any parser in python. If not suggest one and I will try to write a port of it in python and contribute it to the web, so other persons make use of it or at least try it.

So all I want is a python parser to parse Wikipedia dump files. I started writing a manual parser which parses each node and gets the stuff done.

Answer (score 3):

There is example code for the same at http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2009/01/python-parsing-wikipedia-dumps-using.html

Answer (score 2):

Another good module is *mwlib* from [here](http://code.pediapress.com/wiki/wiki/mwlib) - it is a pain to install with all dependencies (at least on Windows), but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about licensing, but [this](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Education/Wikipedia-Dump-Reader-30091.shtml) is implemented in python, and includes the source.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend [mwxml](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwxml). It is a utility for parsing Wikimedia dumps written by [Aaron Halfaker](https://github.com/halfak), a research scientist at the Wikimedia foundation. It can be installed with

```
pip install mwxml
```

Usage is pretty intuitive as demonstrated by this example from the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/mwxml/):

```
>>> import mwxml

>>> dump = mwxml.Dump.from_file(open("dump.xml"))

>>> print(dump.site_info.name, dump.site_info.dbname)
Wikipedia enwiki

>>> for page in dump:
...     for revision in page:
...        print(revision.id)
...
1
2
3
```

It is part of a larger set of [data analysis utilities](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities) put out by the Wikimedia Foundation and its community.